# use .map within .find

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
data = [{timeInterval: {minute: '2022-03-17T15:00:00Z'}, volume: 0.05, high: 0.00001255389794727055, low: 0.00001255389794727055, open: '1.255389794727055'},{timeInterval: {minute: '2022-03-17T15:00:00Z'}, volume: 4, high: 0.000013573032220546603, low: 0.000013573032220546603, open: '1.35730322205466'}]
flattened= [['2022-03-17', '00:00:00.000Z', '386.6'], ['2022-03-18', '00:00:00.000Z', '393.5'],['2022-03-19', '00:00:00.000Z', '400']]
 let bnb_token_ohlc = data.map(x=>
                        {return flattened.find(y=> (x.timeInterval.minute.substring(0, 10))==y[0])}   )
                        console.log(bnb_token_ohlc)
```

(the response to the code above looks a bit weird on here, sorry I don't know how to make it look like it does on the browser console.)
The response I get now:

```
[[ "2022-03-17", "00:00:00.000Z", "386.6" ], [ "2022-03-17", "00:00:00.000Z", "386.6" ]]
```

Hello everyone. With this code I am able to match up the data, the .find works well. Now I want to put another .map within this code for y, I think that will help solve the issue below:

What I need to do, is to have javascript match up when data.timeInterval.minute=flattened[][0], and if these values are equal, take the flattened[3] value and multiply it by data.volume, data.high, data.low, and data.close and then return to me the array called data with these new values inside of it. Currently, I am able to just find when they are equal, but (I think) because the code has .map for data and not for flattened, I am not able to use y[3].

The expected output is something like this:

flattened [3] for the date 2022-03-17 is 386.6 so:

```
[{timeInterval: {minute: '2022-03-17T15:00:00Z'}, volume: 19.33, high: 0.00485333695, low: 0.00485333695, open: '484.580461},..]
```

I have been able to make javascript match up the code as you can see above, but now I need to get a value from a flattened array and multiply it by the values in the data array. I believe I need to do another .map inside of the one I have enough to get it for y, but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `1.255389794727055` * `386.6` should be `485.3336946414795`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the multiplier, and use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy the current element and overwrite the new value on the final return.

```js
const data = [{ 
  timeInterval: { minute: '2022-03-17T15:00:00Z' },
  volume: 0.05,
  high: 0.00001255389794727055,
  low: 0.00001255389794727055,
  open: '1.255389794727055'
}, {
  timeInterval: { minute: '2022-03-17T15:00:00Z' },
  volume: 4,
  high: 0.000013573032220546603,
  low: 0.000013573032220546603,
  open: '1.35730322205466'
}];

const flattened = [
  ['2022-03-17', '00:00:00.000Z', '386.6'],
  ['2022-03-18', '00:00:00.000Z', '393.5'],
  ['2022-03-19', '00:00:00.000Z', '400']
];

const bnb_token_ohlc = data.map(datum => {
  const minute = datum.timeInterval.minute.substring(0, 10);
  const filtered = flattened.filter(a => a[0] === minute)[0];
  const multiplier = filtered ? filtered[2] : 1;
  return {
    ...datum,
    volume: datum.volume * multiplier,
    high: datum.high * multiplier,
    low: datum.low * multiplier,
    open: datum.open * multiplier,
  }
});

console.log(bnb_token_ohlc);
```

---

If you still want to use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

> Replace
>
> ```
> const filtered = flattened.filter(a => a[0] === minute)[0];
> const multiplier = filtered ? filtered[2] : 1;
> ```
>
> With
>
> ```
> const found = flattened.find(a => a[0] === minute);
> const multiplier = found ? found[2] : 1;
> ```

```js
const data = [{ 
  timeInterval: { minute: '2022-03-17T15:00:00Z' },
  volume: 0.05,
  high: 0.00001255389794727055,
  low: 0.00001255389794727055,
  open: '1.255389794727055'
}, {
  timeInterval: { minute: '2022-03-17T15:00:00Z' },
  volume: 4,
  high: 0.000013573032220546603,
  low: 0.000013573032220546603,
  open: '1.35730322205466'
}];

const flattened = [
  ['2022-03-17', '00:00:00.000Z', '386.6'],
  ['2022-03-18', '00:00:00.000Z', '393.5'],
  ['2022-03-19', '00:00:00.000Z', '400']
];

const bnb_token_ohlc = data.map(datum => {
  const minute = datum.timeInterval.minute.substring(0, 10);
  const found = flattened.find(a => a[0] === minute);
  const multiplier = found ? found[2] : 1;
  return {
    ...datum,
    volume: datum.volume * multiplier,
    high: datum.high * multiplier,
    low: datum.low * multiplier,
    open: datum.open * multiplier,
  }
});

console.log(bnb_token_ohlc);
```

---

Or you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sort the *flattened* array into the following format, so that you don't need to re-search the *flattened* array every time.

```
{
  "2022-03-17": "386.6",
  "2022-03-18": "393.5",
  "2022-03-19": "400"
}
```

```js
const data = [{ 
  timeInterval: { minute: '2022-03-17T15:00:00Z' },
  volume: 0.05,
  high: 0.00001255389794727055,
  low: 0.00001255389794727055,
  open: '1.255389794727055'
}, {
  timeInterval: { minute: '2022-03-17T15:00:00Z' },
  volume: 4,
  high: 0.000013573032220546603,
  low: 0.000013573032220546603,
  open: '1.35730322205466'
}];

const flattened = [
  ['2022-03-17', '00:00:00.000Z', '386.6'],
  ['2022-03-18', '00:00:00.000Z', '393.5'],
  ['2022-03-19', '00:00:00.000Z', '400']
];

const multiplierObj = flattened.reduce((accumu, current) => {
  accumu[current[0]] = current[2];
  return accumu;
}, {});

const bnb_token_ohlc = data.map(datum => {
  const minute = datum.timeInterval.minute.substring(0, 10);
  const found = multiplierObj[minute];
  const multiplier = found ? found : 1;
  return {
    ...datum,
    volume: datum.volume * multiplier,
    high: datum.high * multiplier,
    low: datum.low * multiplier,
    open: datum.open * multiplier,
  }
});

console.log(bnb_token_ohlc);
```

Comment: Yes sir/mam your method is better, thank you!

Comment: @Ali I added a method again, if you are interested, you can refer to it again.